# Why the intersection of nonvanishing locus and affine open subscheme is principal open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ be a global section. Let $X_f:=\{ x \in X : f(x)\neq 0 \}$ be the nonvanishing locus ( Here $f(x) \neq 0$ means that $f_x$ is invertible in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ ). Let $U:=\operatorname{Spec}A\subseteq X$ be an affine open subscheme.

Then why $U\cap X_f = D_U(f|_U)$ ( the principal open subset in $U$ ) ?

Comment: The point is that if $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, then $f\in\mathcal{O}_X(X)=A$ and $X_f=D(f)$, pretty much by unwinding definitions.

Comment: @Thorgott : Thanks for hint !